# Firebase dynamic hosting asks for authentication after region change

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have been serving dynamic content with a cloud function for some time.
Now, I tried changing the region of the cloud function by using `region()` in the function builder:

```js
// Old
export const serveContent = functions
    .https
    .onRequest((req, res) => {...})

// New
export const serveContent = functions
    .region("europe-west1")
    .https
    .onRequest((req, res) => {...})
```

During this change I did not modify my `rewrites` in the `firebase.json`.

Now, the requests do not reach the cloud function anymore (there are no invocations shown in the logs) and my browser gets redirected with a `302 Found` status code to a page prompting for authentication. How can I keep serving content without authentication?

[image]

### Edit:

Both cloud functions have the `Cloud Functions-Invoker` role set for `allUsers`:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prompt for authentication is just a side-effect of the real problem. [The docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions) state:

> Firebase Hosting supports Cloud Functions in us-central1 only.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you deploy a function in a new region, Cloud Functions will create a totally different function (unless specified), instead of modifying a previous one. See here how two functions with the same name but different regions are living together:

[image: Two Cloud Functions]

Thus, as it is a different function, [you need to configure the Access Control to it](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing#access_control). Specifically, you can [allow unauthenticated invocation for all users](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#allowing_unauthenticated_http_function_invocation), but I strongly recommend you to take a look on both documentations as it may change due to your requirements and **security concerns**.

On the other hand, you seem to have a typo on your code, but **I believe this is only on your question, not your code, as the error you're reporting is totally different.** Please edit your question if so.

```js
// Old
export const serveContent = functions
   .https
   .onRequest((req, res) => {...})

// New
export const serveContent = function // <- Here. It should be 'functions', not function
   .region("europe-west1")
   .https
   .onRequest((req, res) => {...})
```

Comment: You were right about the typo. I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Great! Did you try setting Access Control as I mentioned? Did it work?

Comment: I've checked and already had the `Cloud Functions-Invoker` role added for `allUsers`. If I understand correctly and that is what you ment, it sadly wasn't the problem.

Comment: Would it be possible that you are trying to access the previous function (at the previous location)? 

Check if the URL follows this form: 
`https://europe-west1-[PROJECT-ID].cloudfunctions.net/[FUNCTION-NAME]`
with the right `region` specified at the beginning (unless you're using a custom domain to [host your function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions)).

Comment: I am using a custom domain, but the 302 redirect send by firebase hosting actually redirects to a `us-central1` domain. Turns out, firebase hosting currently does not support other regions.